# Android Honeycomb network operations

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I've got this problem that I just can't seem to find a way around.

I'm working on an Android app for Honeycomb tablets, and it needs to connect to the internet, download some data and then update the UI once it's done. The thing is, however, that I need to do this any given number of times in succession. My problem right now is that I'm using a Runnable on a new thread with a Handler that updates the UI when the network calls have been made.

My big issue is that I cannot be sure that the data has actually been downloaded to the device yet. All I know is that the network calls are made, and that's it. I cannot be sure if anything's been downloaded.

The big problem in my case lies in the fact that you cannot use the main thread for your network operations in Honeycomb. If I had been using the main thread,

I'd really love some help on this subject. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
I'll try to explain everything a bit better:

I've created a class that makes the network calls in a separate thread, and this class also contains a few methods that return various data from those network calls. However, the network calls can vary in length - depending on the user's network speed - so if I call one of the methods, i.e. getTitle(), I can't be sure that the network call has finished yet.

I need to do something along the lines of this:
'- Create new instance of the class (this beings a download in a new thread)
- Make sure that the download has completed, so I can use the data from it
- Update a progressbar'

That's basically what I need to do. Hope it helped. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All I know is that the network calls are made, and that's it. I cannot be sure if anything's been downloaded.

This doesn't really make sense to me. So you're making the network calls, are you getting a response? Are you storing the data?

You're not really supposed to use the main thread for network connections, do you want the user to be completely paralyzed while these network calls are happening?

If you use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for example, the `onPostExecute(Object object)` gets called when your calls are done and you can daisy chain those network calls using that...

Comment: I've tried to explain it a bit better in the first post. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I still think you should use AsyncTask, have you looked into it? If so, what doesn't it do that you need?

Comment: Well, when I create a new instance of my class, it starts the download on a new thread, and my problem is that I can't return any data from the Runnable.

What I'd really like is to have some way I can create a new instance of my class and make it return the data, however this seems impossible when doing it with a Runnable on a new thread. Could I perhaps use an AsyncTask in the class instead of a Runnable?

Comment: So, as the link describes, AsyncTask does run in a separate thread automatically, that's kinda the point of it. It can't return data synchronously like you want because it takes time to retrieve the data, that's just how remoting works. You'll have to call other methods in the onPostExecute. Please read the link.

Comment: Yeah, but I need something that'll return the data. My code must not be run before the data has been downloaded and is available. Other parts of the code depend on the data that needs to be downloaded.

From what I can read about AsyncTask, there's no way to do what I need to do with it. Any other ideas as to what will work?

Comment: Was just looking back at some old questions of mine, and saw this. Man, I was being foolish :-) AsyncTask was definitely the way to go with this.